# Accessing non-static nested class

Tags: java, inner-classes, static-members, nested-class, non-static

This may be silly to ask, but looking at following code raises a question.

```
public class Outer {
    public class Inner {
        public static final int variable = 100;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int test = Outer.Inner.variable; // Inner Non-Static accessed
                                         // with Class reference?  
    }
}
```

How can the non-static nested class be accessed with a class reference?

Comment: The field `variable` is static, so it can be accessed. That's basically the same concept as with a top-level class.

Comment: A non-static data member can not be accessed statically.  Your example; however, is of a static data member which is accessed statically.

Comment: My query is how can the Non Static nested class 'Inner' be accessed by outer class reference 'Outer' ('Outer.Inner'??), whereas Inner is an Instance member?

Answer (score 3):

The variable is static, and that is what matters. Since the variable is static you can always access it with the class reference.

Comment: Thanks, my query is how can the Non Static nested class 'Inner' be accessed by outer class reference 'Outer' ('Outer.Inner'??), whereas Inner is an Instance member?

Comment: Because you are access the class, not an instance of the class. The inner class exists as a class whether you create instances of it or not.